# Specify sparse range

Tags: google-sheets, range, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have data in rows 1-100 in the first column (a).  Then perhaps I want to rank each of those values excluding the values in rows 32 and 71.

Other spreadsheets allow something like this in b1 to get the rank of a1 (ascending order):

```
=rank(a1,(a1:a31,a33:a70,a71:a100),0)
```

Google Spreadsheets gives an error in b1 if you have a range expression like the one above.

How do I specify a sparse range in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 3):

8/29/12 [ananadvarma](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/5XSa1gpNxg0) wrote "As of now selection of non-contiguous cells is not possible in Google Docs Spread sheets".